# QBFC12 exception for QB v7 IInvoiceLineAdd.get_TaxAmount

Tags: quickbooks, qbfc

QB exception: 0x80040308 IInvoiceLineAdd.get_TaxAmount

I have a currently functioning program that adds invoices to QB via QBFC12.  When I run with QB 2007 it fails with the above error because this version does not support a line item tax amount.  I want to put some check inside the code to test for QB version, but I am unsure of what version to check for.  I know it does not work for 2007 and it has been tested on 2013, but between I do not know.

Is there some documentation for this or can I check something in QBFC to determine if it supports this call?  I checked in the Onscreen Reference in InvoiceLineAdd, but I do not see a field for TaxAmount.

-Rick

Answer (score 0):

Normally, the Onscreen Reference would list what fields are available and in what version, but I don't see a listing for this field for IInvoiceLineAdd. It is a valid field that works with SDK version 7 and higher, as I did some internal testing.